# Android Studio GUI Layout

Tags: android-studio-2.2

Currently the component tree tab and palette tab are combined as image1 shows. I am looking to re-arrange the component tree tab so the component tree and properties tab are combined like in image 2.

Image 1[image]

Image 2[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's obvious that you don't understand the topic of this site. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy But the question is about tools primarily used for programming...